# Use function on any numbers within a string

Tags: php, string, number-formatting

I'm trying to take this to this string

`**string** = 55 Banana Slush 25 Test` into `Fifty five Banana Slush twenty five test`

Now I have the function to convert any numbers to words which is `replaceNumtoWord($number)`

However I need to take the **string**, find each number, then use the function on each number within the string rather then extract the numbers from it.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($match) {
    return replaceNumToWord($match[0]);
}, $str);
```

If you have to use an old PHP version not supporting anonymous functions:

```
function _num2word_cb($match) {
    return replaceNumToWord($match[0]);        
}
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', '_num2word_cb', $str);
```

sidenote: the pattern `\d+` will match any sequence of digits, regardless where they would appear, e.g. it will match 10, 20 and 30 in "my10, 20, 30foo". You can change the pattern to `\b\d+\b` if you want to match only 20.

Comment: deleting mine, upvoting yours since it was earlier and my own solution didnt add anything new.

Comment: My apologies Gordon, I changed the function name and never updated it from your code, seems no errors but there is an issue with my replaceNumToWord function as it's not returning anything. Thanks both TheifMaster and Gordon

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
function transNumber($str) {
  return preg_replace_callback('/\d+/', function($matches){
            return replaceNumtoWord($matches[0]);
         }, $str);
}
```

If your php version < 5.3, then you need to define the function passed to preg_replace_callback.